# .tsx file can't resolve antoher .ts file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-router, react-router-dom

I am writing a typescript react project, and has wrote some routers in `src/router` folder, and in the `src/App.tsx` file, i tried to import the router, but it always told me **can't resolve the file**

```js
// src/router/index.ts

import MainView from './MainView';
import RightView from './RightView';

const FUNCTION_ROUTES = new Set([
  '/',
  '/group_chat/:group_id',
  '/private_chat/:user_id',
  '/setting',
]);

export { MainView, RightView, FUNCTION_ROUTES };
```

```js
// src/App.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import loadable from '@loadable/component';

import { MainView, RightView, FUNCTION_ROUTES } from './router';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="layout-wrapper">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/signup" exact component={loadable(() => import('./containers/SignUp'))} />
          <Route path="/login" exact component={loadable(() => import('./containers/Login'))} />
          <Route exact path={[...FUNCTION_ROUTES]}>
            <Route path={[...FUNCTION_ROUTES]} exact component={MainView} />
            <Route path={[...FUNCTION_ROUTES]} exact component={RightView} />
          </Route>
          <Route component={loadable(() => import('./containers/404'))} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default hot(App);
```

I have checked that the `index.ts` file path is right, but when i tried to start the project, it always told me that

```
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './router' in '/home/yeoman/projects/Graduation P
roject/WebIM/src'
```

So what's wrong with my `App.tsx` file, and how can I import the routers correctly.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "jsx": "react",
    "isolatedModules": true,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,

    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
        "@/*": ["./*"],
    },

    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

    /* Advanced Options */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "ESNext"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig.json?

Comment: I have added it